# autofac resolve issue for keyed values

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am currently working on a feature and added the builder code like this in the Autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<ILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateEvent>>()
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerRequest()
           .Keyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateEvent>>(AuditType.Schedule);

builder.RegisterType<ILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdatePart>>()
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerRequest()
           .Keyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdatePart>>(AuditType.Part);

builder.RegisterType<ILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateTest>>()
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerRequest()
           .Keyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateTest>>(AuditType.Test);
```

This code is run as a console app service and the call to this is made from an api service.I want it to be called as below

```
AutoFacModule autofac = new AutoFacModule();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            autofac.LoadBuilder(builder);
            Container = builder.Build();
            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
var _publisher1 = scope.ResolveKeyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateEvent>>(AuditType.Schedule);

var _publisher2 = scope.ResolveKeyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdatePart>>(AuditType.Part);

var _publisher2 = scope.ResolveKeyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateTest>>(AuditType.Test);
}
```

When i am trying to resolve it using the below code in my implementation class

```
var _publisher = scope.ResolveKeyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateEvent>>(AuditType.Schedule);
```

I am getting the following error

```
Unable to resolve the type Apiconnector.Integrations.Vilt.Service.Providers.Custom.Publish.ILTLoPublisher`1[LMS.ILT.ScheduleUpdateEvent]' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located
```

Comment: Is `IILTLoPublisher` an interface, or a concrete class? It almost looks like you're trying to register an interface without an implementation.

Comment: This is an interface and ILTLoPublisher is the generic class

Comment: ```    public class ILTLoPublisher<T> : IILTLoPublisher<T> where T : Class
    {
  
    }``` this is how its implemented

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed the difference in the number of Is.

Comment: Where are you calling this resolve code from? Is it part of handling a web request? If not, there won't be a request lifetime scope.

Comment: Yes, i am able to resolve for a class like Test inheriting from ITest . This works successfully, but not the above code

Comment: Did I miss someone else's comment? What is your last comment in reference to?

Comment: Also, i am new the IOC and Autofac functionality .

Comment: Please can you answer my question as to where you're calling `scope.ResolveKeyed<....>` - is it as part of handling a web request in ASP.NET? And what is the lifetime of the service that this resolve code belongs to? These are important questions. Without answers to them, it's not possible to understand the problem you're facing.

Comment: I was saying that , builder.RegisterType<Test>().As<ITest>(); works . I am not sure if the issue is with the AsImplementedInterfaces

Comment: OK...and my questions?

Comment: Ok, so this code scope.ResolveKeyed<....> is added a Console App Service. What i am doing is  AutoFacModule autofac = new AutoFacModule();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            autofac.LoadBuilder(builder);
            Container = builder.Build();

Comment: using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            { var _publisher = scope.ResolveKeyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdateEvent>>(AuditType.Schedule);}

Comment: So , these are the things done

Comment: Wait, you're building a console application? `InstancePerRequest` means instance per _web request_ in an ASP.NET context.

Comment: The call to this service is made from another api service

Comment: So could you please let me know how i can use the Autofac to use the dependencies for this?

Comment: You can only resolve dependencies registered with `.InstancePerRequest()` if it's part of a web request (a special lifetime scope is created for web requests). Perhaps you want `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()`?

Comment: I will be having another set of registrations like  builder.RegisterType<ILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdatePart>>()
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerRequest()
           .Keyed<IILTLoPublisher<ScheduleUpdatePart>>(AuditType.Part);

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Tried InstancePerLifetimeScope() also .That also failed

Comment: Hi @Llama, i have edited the question

Comment: Are you sure that `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` didn't work? I [just tried it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q2716P) and it was fine.

Comment: I [can reproduce it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxjpnv) with `InstancePerRequest()` but that makes perfect sense: it's not being resolved as part of a web request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `InstancePerRequest` unless the object being resolved is part of a web request (as noted by the comments on the question). More specifically:

- The executing application must be a web application.
- The executing application needs to have the [Autofac web integration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/index.html) in place.
- The resolution must be happening in that web application as part of a response to an inbound web request - for example, as part of an MVC controller or ASP.NET Core middleware.

The "per request" semantics have nothing to do with the *client making the request* - it's about the *server handling the request*.

[You might want to spend some time with the documentation on the topic.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) There is a section in there about how to implement custom per-request semantics for your app.

If what you are creating is a console app that *takes in requests* from clients (e.g., a self-hosted web application) then you need to:

- Add the existing Autofac web integration for your app type (we do support ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET Core self hosted scenarios); OR
- Implement something custom if you're not using ASP.NET (see that doc I linked).

If what you are creating is a console app that *issues requests as a client* then you should ignore `InstancePerRequest`. Instead:

- Create a new lifetime scope around each request (like you're doing) and treat that as a unit of work.
- Register components as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` so there will be just one for the duration of that lifetime scope.

That said, without a minimal repro it's hard to see what you're doing beyond that to provide any sort of guidance.

Since you mentioned you're pretty new to all this, it would be *very* worth your time checking out [the Autofac documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to start understanding concepts like this as well as looking in the [Examples repo](https://github.com/autofac/Examples) where there are working examples of many different application types to show you how things work.